# Implement 2 classes for ActionListener for buttons

Tags: java, class, actionlistener

I have 2 classes, the first class is where I am creating GUI and all of the components needed. Including the buttons. This is being done outside of the main method and in there own respective methods. I want to .addActionListener, but from another class outside of this one. I do not want to use inner classes.

Here is the classes containing Main and the Gui components and the button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PasswordGeneratorGui {

private JFrame interfaceFrame;
private JPanel interfacePanel;
private JMenuBar interfaceMenuBar;
private JMenu interfaceMenu;
private JMenuItem interfaceMenuItemFile;
private JButton interfaceButtonGenerate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PasswordGeneratorGui();
}

public PasswordGeneratorGui() {
    createInterfacePanel();
    createInterfaceFrame();
    createInterfaceMenuBar();
    createInterfaceMenu();
    createInterfaceMenuItem();
    createInterfaceButton();

    PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler b = new PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler();

    interfaceFrame.add(interfacePanel);
    interfaceFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void createInterfacePanel() {
    interfacePanel = new JPanel();
    interfacePanel.setLayout(null);
}

public void createInterfaceFrame() {
    interfaceFrame = new JFrame();
    interfaceFrame.setTitle("Password Generator");
    interfaceFrame.setBounds(50, 50, 700, 400);
    interfaceFrame.setResizable(false);
    interfaceFrame.setJMenuBar(interfaceMenuBar);
}   

public void createInterfaceMenuBar() {
    interfaceMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    interfaceMenuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 20);
    interfaceMenuBar.setVisible(true);
    interfacePanel.add(interfaceMenuBar);
}

public void createInterfaceMenu() {
    interfaceMenu = new JMenu("File");
    interfaceMenuBar.add(interfaceMenu);
}

public void createInterfaceMenuItem() {
    interfaceMenuItemFile = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    interfaceMenu.add(interfaceMenuItemFile);
}

**public void createInterfaceButton() {
    interfaceButtonGenerate = new JButton("Generate");
    interfaceButtonGenerate.setBounds(0, 358, 700, 20);
    interfaceButtonGenerate.addActionListener();
    interfacePanel.add(interfaceButtonGenerate);
}**
}
```

Here is the class for the ActionListener

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler generate = new PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler();

public PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler() {

}

public void interfaceButtonGenerateHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(1); 
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I just want to be able to call the AcitonListener method from the second class. I have tried initiating a new instance of the class and calling it however I think I wasn't quite going in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what your asking.  You said

> I just want to be able to call the AcitonListener method from the second class

Taken literally this means that while you're inside of the `PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler` class, you want to call the `actionPerformed()` method.  If so, just use `this.actionPerformed()`, where `this` is a [special keyword in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), representing the current instance of your class.

---

If however you want to add your handler to the button you created in the first class, which seems like what you might want to do, then you just need to call the [`JButton#addActionListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) method.

```
public PasswordGeneratorGui() {
    createInterfacePanel();
    createInterfaceFrame();
    createInterfaceMenuBar();
    createInterfaceMenu();
    createInterfaceMenuItem();
    createInterfaceButton();

    PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler b = new PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler();
    interfaceButtonGenerate.addActionListener(b); // Add handler to button

    interfaceFrame.add(interfacePanel);
    interfaceFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, inside of the `PasswordGeneratorButtonHandler` class, you instantiate an instance of the class called `generate`.  This is unnecessary.